# Decoding time, presented in a weird format

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this unusual time format.

```
t1367071200
```

or

```
t1367063100
```

Google does not say much but they do say it's a time like `18:00`. Do you have any clue how to read this string so that I can figure out the time? Or something I can read about it cuz I'm seeing this for the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp):

```
In [2]: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1367071200)
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 27, 18, 0)

In [4]: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int('t1367071200'[1:]))
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 27, 18, 0)
```

- [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp)

Answer (score 1):

It's a Unix timestamp, you can use the `time` module or `datetime` module convert it to human readable form:

```
[11]: strs="t1367071200"

In [12]: import time

In [13]: time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(float(strs[1:])))
Out[13]: '2013-04-27 14:00:00'
```